# Debugging solr rss DataImportHandler

Tags: solr

I have an existing collection, to which I want to add an RSS importer.  I've copied what I could gleam from the example-DIH/solr/rss code.

The details are below, but the bottom line is that everything seems to run, but it always says "Fetched: 0" (and I get no documents).  There are no exceptions in the tomcat log.

Questions:

- Is there a way to turn up debugging on rss importers?
- Can I see solr's actual request and response?
- What would cause the request to succeed, but no rows to be fetched?
- Is there a tutorial for *adding* an RSS DIH to an *existing* collection?

Thanks!

My solrconfig.xml file contains the requestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">rss-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And rss-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="slashdot"
                pk="link"
                url="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/rss/channel | /rss/item"
                transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

            <field column="source_name" xpath="/rss/channel/title" commonField="true" />

            <field column="title" xpath="/rss/item/title" />
            <field column="link" xpath="/rss/item/link" />
            <field column="body" xpath="/rss/item/description" />
            <field column="date" xpath="/rss/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

and from  schema.xml:

```
<fields>
   <field name="title" type="text_general" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="link" type="string" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="source_name" type="text_general" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="body" type="text_general" required="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
   <field name="date" type="date" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<fields>
```

When I run the dataimport from the admin web page, it all seems to go well.  It shows "Requests: 1" and there are no exceptions in the tomcat log:

```
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:58 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter maybeReloadConfiguration
INFO: Loading DIH Configuration: rss-data-config.xml
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:58 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter loadDataConfig
INFO: Data Configuration loaded successfully
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:58 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:58 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:59 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
INFO: Time taken = 0:0:0.693
Mar 12, 2013 9:02:59 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: [articles] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={optimize=false&clean=false&indent=true&commit=false&verbose=true&entity=slashdot&command=full-import&debug=true&wt=json} {} 0 706
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is due to your rss-data-config.xml and the defined xpaths.

If you open the url http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot in Internet Explorer and hit F12 for developer tools it will show you the structure of the HTML.

You can see that the node `<item>` is a child of `<channel>` and not `<rss>`. So your config should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
<document>
<entity name="slashdot"
            pk="link"
            url="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot"
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            forEach="/rss/channel | /rss/channel/item"
            transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

        <field column="source_name" xpath="/rss/channel/title" commonField="true" />

        <field column="title" xpath="/rss/channel/item/title" />
        <field column="link" xpath="/rss/channel/item/link" />
        <field column="body" xpath="/rss/channel/item/description" />
        <field column="date" xpath="/rss/channel/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Let me give it a try when I unbury myself from this other module.  Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that this feature was not important to the project (as I have to save the feed data anyway in case of reload), and I've moved it to cloudsearch.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Which Solr version are you using ?

For 3.X you have the [debug](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands) feature with DIH which will help you debug step by step.
Its missing in 4.X probably check [SOLR-4151](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4151)

Comment: 4.1.0.  SOLR-4151 is closed, and I don't see that it offers any workarounds or other assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The following data-config.xml file does the work for Slashdot (Solr 4.2.0)

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="HttpDataSource" />
<document>
<entity name="slashdot"
    pk="link"
    url="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot"
    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
    forEach="/rss/channel/item"
    transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

    <field column="title"        xpath="/rss/channel/item/title" />
    <field column="link"         xpath="/rss/channel/item/link" />
    <field column="description"  xpath="/rss/channel/item/description" />
    <field column="creator"      xpath="/rss/channel/item/creator" />
    <field column="item-subject" xpath="/rss/channel/item/subject" />

    <field column="slash-department" xpath="/rss/channel/item/department" />
    <field column="slash-section"    xpath="/rss/channel/item/section" />
    <field column="slash-comments"   xpath="/rss/channel/item/comments" />
    <field column="date" xpath="/rss/channel/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

Notice the extra 'Z' on the dateTimeFormat, which is necessary according to "schema.xml"

Quoting schema.xml

> The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and
>            is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime
>            http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime
>            The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.
>            Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
>            All other components are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update your rss-data-config.xml as below

'<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="slashdot"
                pk="link"
                url="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/RDF/channel | /RDF/item"
                transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

            <field column="source"       xpath="/RDF/channel/title"   commonField="true" />
            <field column="source-link"  xpath="/RDF/channel/link"    commonField="true" />
            <field column="subject"      xpath="/RDF/channel/subject" commonField="true" />

            <field column="title"        xpath="/RDF/item/title" />
            <field column="link"         xpath="/RDF/item/link" />
            <field column="description"  xpath="/RDF/item/description" />
            <field column="creator"      xpath="/RDF/item/creator" />
            <field column="item-subject" xpath="/RDF/item/subject" />

            <field column="slash-department" xpath="/RDF/item/department" />
            <field column="slash-section"    xpath="/RDF/item/section" />
            <field column="slash-comments"   xpath="/RDF/item/comments" />
            <field column="date" xpath="/RDF/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>'

It worked for me
```

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Comment: I am using solr 6.0.0. First I tried with /rss/, but it did not worked for me. Only worked when I used /RDF/